# Animate TableView Cells in Swift (Up into TableView) on Loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this code that is setup so that it calls and animates the tableview cells up upon displaying. How could I set this up so it only animates the cells in that appear on the initial loading of the view?

Thanks in advance...

```
  var preventAnimation = Set<NSIndexPath>()

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // 
    if !preventAnimation.contains(indexPath) {
        preventAnimation.insert(indexPath)
        let rotationTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, +600, 0)
        cell.layer.transform = rotationTransform
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a variable `maxCellIndexAppeared` to recode the maximum `indexPath.row` for the cell that have appeared,it better than using a set to contain all the indexPath.

In the initialize method set `maxCellIndexAppeared` to zero,and then compare it with the `indexPath.row` when the cell will display,if current cell indexPath greater than the variable then do your animation otherwise return.

**Just like this:**

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if maxCellIndexAppeared > indexPath.row {
           return
        }

        //here reset the current maximum index
        maxCellIndexAppeared = indexPath.row
        //And then do your animation
       ....do your animation.....
   }
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of such a simple solution. I guess I should be taking myself to bed ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare Bool array which will keep track of the rows which are animated 
var animationShown : [Bool]? 


// Initalize animationShown array in your viewDidLoad 
self.animationShown = [Bool] (repeating: false, count: YourTableViewRowsCount)


// MARK: - Animate Tableview Cell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
if self.animationShown?[indexPath.row] == false
{
//Transform Animation
let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -200, 0, 0)
cell.layer.transform = transform
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:
{
cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
})
self.animationShown?[indexPath.row] = true
}
}

Hope this helps!! Happy Coding...
```